# Filter out all instances of one string from another string in java

Tags: java, string, methods, filter

I want to create a method called filterOut that accepts two string as arguments and returns the first string with all instances of the second string removed. Ex: filterOut("hello my friend, how are you?" , "h"); returns "ello my friend, ow are you?" and filterOut("abchelloabcfriendabc" , "abc"); returns "hellofriend"

```
    public static String filterOut(String phrase, String second){
         int counter = 0;
         int length = phrase.length();
         String filtered = "";
         while(counter < length){
             String letter = phrase.substring(counter, counter + 1);
             if(!letter.equals(second)){
                 filtered = filtered + letter;
             }
             counter++;
         }
         return filtered;

    public static void main(String args[]){
         String next = filterOut("hello my friend, how are you?" , "h");
         System.out.println(next);                     
     }
```

This code only works for the first example when I use it in the main method. How can I get it to work for the second example as well?

Comment: Why cant you use str.relaceAll() method.

Comment: I think `replaceAll` is overkill. `replace` already replaces each substring that matches the target sequence. I think the difference is that `replaceAll` recognizes regular expressions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot use the replace method

Comment: @user2206097 `replaceAll("h", "")`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

`str1.replace(str2, "");`

Or in your example,

`second.replace(phrase, "");`

Also: there is no need to write a method for this, when there already is one :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot use the replace method

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
public static String filterOut(String phrase) {
    return phrase.replace(phrase, "");
}
```

**Edit**:
You can also use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
public static String filterOut(String phrase, String second) {
    String filtered = "";
    for (String each : phrase.split(second)) {
        filtered = filtered + each;
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Your method wont work because you are comparing character by character in the below line. So that's why it will work for `filterOut("hello my friend, how are you?" , "h");` and not work for input `filterOut("abchelloabcfriendabc" , "abc");`

```
 String letter = phrase.substring(counter, counter + 1);
 if(!letter.equals(second)){
     filtered = filtered + letter;
 }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot use the replace method